# Making 1% milk into whole milk

Tags: yeast, rolls

I have a yeast Roll recipe that calls for 1 cup of whole milk. I only have 1% milk. What can I do to make the 1% equivalent to whole milk.

Answer (score 7):

You can't directly make whole milk out of lowfat milk and milkfat. But if you like, you can try adding back some fat to the recipe -- melted butter or vegetable oil -- at the concentration of, I suppose, 2.5%. (If the recipe already includes one of these, just increase the amount.) The result will not be quite the same, but will be very close.

In a yeasted bread, though, the difference between 1% and whole milk probably won't be significant. I'd just use the 1% milk, and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add half and half to your skim milk, about 1 tablespoon (half ounce) per cup of 1% milk to make a new cup of whole milk (slightly more than a cup).

Answer (score 2):

Whole milk is 4% fat, so you need to increase your fat by 3%. Essentially you need to substitute 3ml of fat for 3ml of milk per 100ml, which is just over half a teaspoon. 1 tsp is 5ml, so you can substitute tsp of milk for fat per 200ml. Butter is 80% fat, so you can use that. Cream is anywhere up to 60% fat so if you are going to add cream instead you'll need to factor that in.

Answer (score 0):

This is my go to since I don't buy whole milk & so far it's been a great substitution for all of my recipes.

To make whole milk out of skim milk and heavy cream:
Use 1½ Tablespoons of heavy cream and the balance skim milk to make one cup.
To make whole milk out of 1% milk and Whipping Cream: Use 1 Tablespoon of heavy cream and the balance 1% milk to make one cup.”

[Milk and Cream Substitution - Cooking Tip of the Day](https://cookingtipoftheday.blogspot.com/2010/04/milk-and-cream-substitution.html)